# Update tile image from web source - windows 8 app

Tags: c#, templates, windows-8, windows-store-apps, tile

Windows 8 app - metro app - Hi I want update tile image from web but I can not get it to work. I use this [Link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Tile-Update-every-minute-68dbbbff) 
I only made some small customization but image from web not working for me. I have image in string src1 , if I use **const string src1 = "ms-appx:///Assets/clock24x24.png";** then image working but from web it not working. Does anyone have some idea?

```
public static void CreateSchedule()
    {


        var tileUpdater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
        var plannedUpdated = tileUpdater.GetScheduledTileNotifications();
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime planTill = now.AddHours(4);

        const string src1 = "http://cdn.thenextweb.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/02/Screen-Shot-2012-02-21-at-4.48.56-PM.png";

        DateTime updateTime = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, 0).AddMinutes(1);
        if (plannedUpdated.Count > 0)
            updateTime = plannedUpdated.Select(x => x.DeliveryTime.DateTime).Union(new [] { updateTime }).Max();
        string xml = "<tile>"
                         + "<visual>"
                         + "<binding template='TileWideImageAndText01'>"
                         + "<text id='1'>This tile notification uses web images</text>"
                         + "<image id='1' src='" + src1 + "' alt='Web image'/>"
                         + "</binding>"
                         + "<binding template='TileSquareImage'>"
                         + "<image id='1' src='" + src1 + "' alt='Web image'/>"
                         + "</binding>"
                         + "</visual>"
                         + "</tile>";
        var tileXmlNow = string.Format(xml);
        XmlDocument documentNow = new XmlDocument();
        documentNow.LoadXml(tileXmlNow);

        tileUpdater.Update(new TileNotification(documentNow) { ExpirationTime = now.AddMinutes(1) });

        for (var startPlanning = updateTime; startPlanning < planTill; startPlanning = startPlanning.AddMinutes(1))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(startPlanning);
            Debug.WriteLine(planTill);

            try
            {
                var tileXml = string.Format(xml);
                XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
                document.LoadXml(tileXml);

                ScheduledTileNotification scheduledNotification = new ScheduledTileNotification(document, new DateTimeOffset(startPlanning)) { ExpirationTime = startPlanning.AddMinutes(1) };
                tileUpdater.AddToSchedule(scheduledNotification);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you activated the Internet functionality in your package AppxManifest file?